# What is the correct syntax for importing JSNLog using ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs, jsnlog

I can't seem to figure out how to import JSNLog into my ES6 (babel) based Aurelia project.  I've tried:

```
import 'jsnlog';            // JL is undefined
import JL from 'jsnlog';    // JL is {}
import {JL} from 'jsnlog';  // JL is undefined
```

If it matters I've learned that the jsnlog.js file is generated from typescript source.

Comment: You could try to compile jsnlog from typescript to ES6, then let babel do the rest.

Comment: I'd prefer to consume the JSNLog distribution directly (if possible), without needing a custom build step for a dependency.

Comment: In that case the first one should work - the lib defines a global. What code does babel create for this, what module loader/bundler are you using, how do you inject the distributed library in your module repository?

Comment: The JL variable is undefined when I use #1.  The jsnlog.js file is a "format cjs" style CommonJS module that was directly generated by TypeScript.

Comment: How did you install `jsnlog`? What version? which version of Babel? For me, `import { JL } from 'jsnlog'` works as expected after `npm install jsnlog`. I am using `babel-cli@6.5.1` and I installed `jsnlog@2.17.0`.

Comment: This is client\browser code so I installed with `jspm install npm:jsnlog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author has fixed this [issue](http://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/issues/24) with the [v2.17.1](https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/releases/tag/v2.17.1) release.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of JSNLog.

Just added info to the jsnlog.com site about using ES6 import to import JSNLog into an ES6 NodeJs application:
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/LoadingJsFile#es6
(using Babel as the transpiler).

This uses:

```
import {JL} from 'jsnlog';
```

Comment: My issue is using jsnlog in a client application.  Tracking the issue here: https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/issues/24

Answer (score 1):

According to [this line](https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.js/blob/master/jsnlog.js#L858) from the source code the following

```
import {JL} from 'jsnlog';
```

should work. At least, it works for me.

If it doesn't, check out your SystemJS setup. The issue will be somewhere there.